# Best method to replace the first instance of text with nested brackets in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I'm relatively new to Linux/Bash and I'm working through the following guide as a tutorial for myself:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-centos-7

Rather than just doing this by hand though, I'm also trying to write a bash script that will perform all the steps in that guide.

I'm stuck on the following step: the guide has you install nginx and then remove the following block of text from the nginx.conf file:

```
    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }enter code here

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

I was attempting to accomplish this using sed, using a command along the lines of:

```
sed -i '/server {/,/ location = /50x.html {            }        }/d' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

but I wasn't able to get it to match the end of the block successfully (regex/special characters/whitespace errors that I couldn't figure out, e.g. "sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unterminated address regex"). I tried escaping the special characters but was still stuck.

I gave up on that and instead just opted to delete a fixed number of lines following a match at the start of the block:

```
sudo sed -i '/server {/,+19d' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

which worked, but also deleted another block started with '/server {/' in commented out text elsewhere in the file which I did not want. I searched but was unable to find a way to only delete after the first match with this command. I saw suggestions along the lines of:

```
sudo sed -i '0,/server {/,+19d' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

but these returned the error: sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unknown command: `,'

So in sum my questions are:

How do you remove a block of nested brackets using sed? If it's not possible then what is a better tool to use? And how do I only do the removal on the first matched occurrence?

Thank you very much for reading and any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you have a problem that involves *nesting* constructs (parentheses, braces, and the like), you can immediately know that this problem is too difficult for `sed`, or indeed any tool that works only with regular expressions.  This is a consequence of computational theory, and there's a decent background explanation on this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton): basically, regular expressions implement only finite state automata, but you need something with the computing power of a pushdown automaton.

Another way to put this is that "regular expressions can't count": in a generic regexp executor, any number of open parentheses "(((" (possibly with any number of non-parenthesis characters between them) are ended by a single close parenthesis ")".  You can write (exceedingly complicated) regexps that can handle three-parentheses groups differently from two-parentheses groups and both of those differently from one-parenthesis groups, but then someone comes along and writes "((((" at you and blows up your complicated scheme.  So then you write one exponentially more complicated to handle groups with *four* parentheses, and then someone gives you five... :-)

Anyway, the upshot is that you need a more powerful language.  These *do* exist, and you can write your own in bash script (since bash implements arithmetic), but there are no standard-out-of-the-box answers for these.  Most people write small parsers in whatever language they find convenient—or you can use Python and the `ply` package, or bison or yacc (included in Linux) with C or C++, though these are actually full grown tools for writing the parsing parts of compilers.

You can also write a full parser in awk, using awk's regular expressions to implement the tokenizer.  I have done this for toy examples, but don't recommend it: once you learn how to use lex and yacc (or ply in Python), you may find that using those is actually easier.  Since they're pretty fully featured, you can write real tools with them.

I'd recommend using ply here since Python provides all the complicated storage-management bits in an easy to use way.  Just be aware that lexing and parsing is a fairly big topic, leading into compilers, which is an even bigger topic.  The concepts of tokenization and parsing aren't that hard, there's just a mind-boggling array of mathematics underpinning the different *methods* of doing it, and what a *context-free grammar* means and implies (follow the Wikipedia links).

---

Edit: here's a complete implementation using just the scanner part of ply.  It's a bit long, but it shows how to use ply to build a lexer, then use it in a rather cheesy way.

I don't know if my treatment of strings and other tokens is correct here since the documentation on the nginx input file format is rather thin, but since the tokens are defined by regular expression, it should be easy to adjust if needed.  I also don't claim it to be a particularly good way to implement an nginx input file parser: if you really wanted to *read and interpret* the file, rather than just crudely hack it up, you'd probably want something at least a little different, perhaps including a proper grammar.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import collections
import sys

import ply.lex

t_COMMENT = r'\#.*'
t_BACKSLASHED = r'\\([\\{}])'
t_WORD = '[A-Za-z0-9_]+'
t_STRING = '("[^"]*")|' "('[^']*)'"
t_LB = '{'
t_RB = '}'
t_WHITE = '[ \t]+'
t_REST = '.'

tokens = [
   'COMMENT',
   'BACKSLASHED',
   'WORD',
   'STRING',
   'LB',
   'RB',
   'WHITE',
   'REST',
   'NEWLINE',
]

def t_NEWLINE(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)
    return t

# This never happens because '.' matches anything but newline and
# we have a newline rule; but if we don't define it, ply complains.
def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)

# Build the lexer
LEXER = ply.lex.lex()

def fill(tlist, howmany):
    "build up token list - returns False if the list is all non-tokens"
    while len(tlist) < howmany:
        tlist.append(LEXER.token())
    return tlist[0] is not None

def nth_is(tlist, offset, tok_type, tok_value=None):
    "a sleazy kind of parser lookahead"
    fill(tlist, offset + 1)
    tok = tlist[offset]
    if tok is None:
        return False
    if tok.type != tok_type:
        return False
    if tok_value is not None and tok.value != tok_value:
        return False
    return True

TEST_DATA = '''\
# a comment - gets copied
server {
    stuff;
    more { } stuff;
    this is not a brace \{ because it is backslashed;
    "and these strings }";
    'do not close the server } either';
}
this gets copied;
'''

def main():
    "main"

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--test', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('inputfile', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'),
                        default=sys.stdin)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.test:
        LEXER.input(TEST_DATA)
    else:
        LEXER.input(args.inputfile.read())

    # Tokenize; copy lines through except when dealing
    # with the first "server" definition
    looking_for_server = True
    copying = True
    eat_white_space_and_newline = False
    brace_depth = 0
    tlist = collections.deque()
    while fill(tlist, 1):
        if tlist[0].type == 'LB':
            brace_depth += 1
        elif tlist[0].type == 'RB':
            if brace_depth > 0:
                brace_depth -= 1
                # If we went from 1 to 0 and are in
                # non-copy mode, resume copying, but eat
                # one white-space-and-newline
                if brace_depth == 0 and not copying:
                    copying = True
                    eat_white_space_and_newline = True
                    tlist.popleft() # eat the }
                    continue
        if looking_for_server:
            check = 0
            if tlist[0].type == 'WHITE':
                fill(tlist, 2)
                check = 1
            else:
                check = 0
            if nth_is(tlist, check, 'WORD', 'server'):
                # server followed by spaces and {, or by { => stop copying
                if nth_is(tlist, check + 1, 'LB') or (
                        nth_is(tlist, check + 1, 'WHITE') and
                        nth_is(tlist, check + 2, 'LB')):
                    copying = False
                    looking_for_server = False
                if check > 0:
                    tlist.popleft() # toss white space at 0 now
            # We'll increment brace-depth when we actually consume
            # the brace.
        if copying:
            if not eat_white_space_and_newline or \
                    tlist[0].type not in ('NEWLINE', 'WHITE'):
                print(tlist[0].value, end='')
            if tlist[0].type == 'NEWLINE':
                eat_white_space_and_newline = False
        tlist.popleft()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        sys.exit(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit('\nInterrupted')
```

Comment: A full-blown parser is serious overkill when you can whip up a reasonably robust *partial* parser in Awk in a few minutes. It would be nice if nginx used a standard configuration file format which can be modified programmatically with ease, but we are stuck for now with this ad-hoc bracketed blocks format.

Comment: @tripleee: nginx configuration format isn't *too* awful (https://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#conf_structure) but it's at least worth handling comments so that you don't get clobbered by malformed commented out sections. (Not that this has happened to me in nginx configurations, but it *has* happened in others...) Also, it's not clear to me what unclosed string quotes do in nginx. See also http://siawyoung.com/coding/sysadmin/nginx/nginx-configuration-syntax.html

Comment: Oh, I agree, but we are still stuck creating ad-hoc parsers - with all their problems, including brittleness and wasted developer time - instead of using standard tools.

Comment: Yes, [if only there were a standard for configuration files](https://xkcd.com/927/). :-)

Comment: @tripleee A configuration format that can be modified by off-the-shelf tools like json, xml or yaml may sound nice in the first place. There is just one problem with that: Except of xml, both json and yaml don't define any order of nodes. (Furthermore json doesn't allow comments which sucks!) While I personally have no problem with xml, I don't think that they will use it. :) An idea would be that nginx, which must have libraries to parse the config file, would expose a shell tool to modify the config. ...

Comment: But again, I doubt that nginx has the ability to preserve the order of expressions (including comments) once the config is parsed. Having all that, imo the best way is to have the nginx configuration being a template rendered by a configuration management tool.

Answer (score 2):

Given this input file:

```
$ cat file
foo
    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }enter code here

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
bar
```

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT and the 3rd arg to match() you can print the target string with:

```
$ cat tst.awk   
BEGIN { RS = "[[:blank:]]*server {" }
NR==2 {
    str = prevRT
    openCnt = 1
    while ( openCnt && match($0,/([{}])(.*)/,a) ) {
        str = str substr($0,1,RSTART)
        openCnt += (a[1] == "{" ? 1 : -1)
        $0 = a[2]
    }
    print str
}
{ prevRT = RT }
```

e.g.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }enter code here

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

and just reverse the logic to print everything except that string:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS = "[[:blank:]]*server {"; ORS="" }
NR==2 {
    openCnt = 1
    while ( openCnt && match($0,/([{}])(.*)/,a) ) {
        str = str substr($0,1,RSTART)
        openCnt += (a[1] == "{" ? 1 : -1)
        $0 = a[2]
    }
    sub(/^[[:blank:]]*\n/,"")
}
{ print $0 (NR>1 ? RT : "") }
```

e.g.:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

The industry standard answer here is: Use a configuration management tool like [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), [Puppet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_(software)), [SaltStack](https://saltstack.com/), [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/) or other competitors.

The basic idea is to make the configuration a template, use a template engine and render it instead of modifying it. The solutions named above do all come with the ability to render config file templates.